# pyspark streaming - checkpoint files did not be cleaned automatically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

My code is like below

```
def process(time, rdd):
    # do something with "previous_batch"
    df = df.cache().checkpoint()
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("previous_batch")
    del df

stream.foreachRDD(process)
```

I use this method to access the dataframe in previous batch. This is running on single node standalone cluster, so the checkpoint directory is set to /tmp. I expected that Spark will automatic delete checkpoint files after a period of time. But **none of checkpoint files is deleted**. I cannot figure out how to clean the checkpoint directory. Otherwise, the disk will run out of space when it runs for a long time.
Should I run another process to clean the files by myself?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43671757/1531971

Comment: df.cache().checkpoint() will save rdd to both memory and disk.Does it necessary?

Comment: @ZhangTong Actually, this dataframe will be reused in this function so I thought caching will faster. And checkpoint is for cutting lineage of the rdd. Is it enough to use checkpoint only?